# Changing the Visibility of a Graphic

Tags: c#, visibility

I am making a hangman game and I need each body part of a drawing to become invisible and then come back as the player guesses the wrong letter. I have tried using picture boxes but they cut off parts of the other images that fall inside the box so I used graphics instead. Here is the code that makes the character depending on who the character selects...

```
 Graphics test = e.Graphics;
        Graphics t2 = e.Graphics;
        //test.DrawImage(Cowboy.head, 180f, 180f, 250f, 250f);
        //test.DrawImage(Cowgirl.head, 35f, 90f, 650f, 550f);
        //test.DrawImage(Criminal.head, 35f, 80f, 650f, 550f);
        //test.DrawImage(Cyborg.head, 180f, 180f, 200f, 350f);
        //test.DrawImage(Princess.head, 180f, 180f, 200f, 350f);
        if (Variables.p1_type=="Cowboy")
        {

            test.DrawImage(Cowboy.head, 180f, 180f, 250f, 250f);
            test.DrawImage(Cowboy.body, 180f, 180f, 250f, 250f);
            test.DrawImage(Cowboy.leftArm, 180f, 180f, 250f, 250f);
            test.DrawImage(Cowboy.rightArm, 180f, 180f, 250f, 250f);
            test.DrawImage(Cowboy.leftLeg, 180f, 180f, 250f, 250f);
            test.DrawImage(Cowboy.rightLeg, 180f, 180f, 250f, 250f);


        }

        if (Variables.p1_type == "Cowgirl")
        {
            test.DrawImage(Cowgirl.head, 35f, 90f, 650f, 550f);
            test.DrawImage(Cowgirl.body, 35f, 90f, 650f, 550f);
            test.DrawImage(Cowgirl.leftArm, 35f, 90f, 650f, 550f);
            test.DrawImage(Cowgirl.rightArm, 35f, 90f, 650f, 550f);
            test.DrawImage(Cowgirl.leftLeg, 35f, 90f, 650f, 550f);
            test.DrawImage(Cowgirl.rightLeg, 35f, 90f, 650f, 550f);
        }

        if (Variables.p1_type == "Criminal")
        {
            test.DrawImage(Criminal.head, 35f, 80f, 650f, 550f);
            test.DrawImage(Criminal.body, 35f, 80f, 650f, 550f);
            test.DrawImage(Criminal.leftArm, 35f, 80f, 650f, 550f);
            test.DrawImage(Criminal.rightArm, 35f, 80f, 650f, 550f);
            test.DrawImage(Criminal.leftLeg, 35f, 80f, 650f, 550f);
            test.DrawImage(Criminal.rightLeg, 35f, 80f, 650f, 550f);
        }

        if (Variables.p1_type == "Cyborg")
        {
            test.DrawImage(Cyborg.head, 180f, 180f, 200f, 350f);
            test.DrawImage(Cyborg.body, 180f, 180f, 200f, 350f);
            test.DrawImage(Cyborg.leftArm, 180f, 180f, 200f, 350f);
            test.DrawImage(Cyborg.rightArm, 180f, 180f, 200f, 350f);
            test.DrawImage(Cyborg.leftLeg, 180f, 180f, 200f, 350f);
            test.DrawImage(Cyborg.rightLeg, 180f, 180f, 200f, 350f);
        }

        if (Variables.p1_type == "Princess")
        {
            test.DrawImage(Princess.head, 180f, 180f, 200f, 350f);
            test.DrawImage(Princess.body, 180f, 180f, 200f, 350f);
            test.DrawImage(Princess.leftArm, 180f, 180f, 200f, 350f);
            test.DrawImage(Princess.rightArm, 180f, 180f, 200f, 350f);
            test.DrawImage(Princess.leftLeg, 180f, 180f, 200f, 350f);
            test.DrawImage(Princess.rightLeg, 180f, 180f, 200f, 350f);
        }
```

I need each of these body parts to start off invisible and then become visible when the wrong character is picked. How can I do this and if it isn't possible what are other ways to do it?

if player guesses wrong

```
   if (Variables.word4player1.ToUpper().Contains(e.KeyCode.ToString())!=true)
                {


                    p1Turn = false;
                    label2.Font = new Font(label1.Font, FontStyle.Underline | FontStyle.Bold);//change underlined player
                    label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font, FontStyle.Regular);
                    p1_wrong.Text = p1_wrong.Text + " " + e.KeyCode.ToString();

                }
```

sets variable p1_type

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Variables.p1_type= listBox_P1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        label_player1Type.Text = Variables.p1_type;
    }
```

Comment: We might need to see the code for how users enter the wrong character...

Comment: Okay, I added it at the bottom of the post.

Comment: That doesn't show what sets `Variables.p1_type`

Comment: I added that too. I really just need to know how to make all of the graphics invisible and I think I can figure out the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "trick" the form into painting the images **ONLY** instead of the whole `PictureBox`.

Of course, there are more "elegant" way of doing this such as override the PictureBox `OnPaint` event or make your own control.

But I myself is not a master of it, so I'm not going to answer you with that.

All you have to do first is set all the `PictureBoxs'` visibility to false.

Then add "false" to each PictureBox's `Tag`. We are going to use this as the "Dummy Visibility" to tell the form to paint the image or not.

In the form's `Paint` event, add:

(Assuming `pbs` is the array that contains all the `PictureBoxs`.)

```
Graphics g = e.Graphics;

for(int i=0;i<pbs.Count();i++)
{
    if(pbs[i].Tag.ToString()=="true") 
        g.DrawImage(pbs[i].Image, pbs[i].Location);
}
```

And in the method that check if the player type in the wrong word, do:

(Assuming `cur` is the index of current `PictureBox`.)

```
pbs[cur].Tag = true;
this.Refresh();
```

And VOILA! You got a `PictureBox` that won't block the image behind it!

Comment: The *more "elegant" way of doing this such as override the PictureBox OnPaint* that's what it looks like he using in how he gets the Graphics object `Graphics test = e.Graphics;`. Upvoted never the less.

Comment: Well, then I guess all he is missing is the "Dummy Visibility". Thanks for your upvote! ^o^